# Issue with web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

i am working with ASP.Net web API's.I have created a folder named api in controllers folder and then created an Api controller in that api folder.
In the admin controller i have simply placed the following code to check wheather the api is working or not.

```
public class AdminController : ApiController
{
    DBEntities _context;
    public AdminController()
    {
        _context = new DBEntities();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
    {

        return new string[] { "Muhammad","Ali"};
    }
}
```

Then from browser i am calling **http://localhost:57368/api/admin** but it gives me "The resource cannot be found" with http 404 error code.It should atleast return JSON result but gives this error instead.
Any help is highly appreciated.
And when i go to network tab in chrome it shows the following details of the request:[image: Click to view error details]

Comment: Why did you tag this as Razor?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        });
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
   }
```

Your global.asax.cs should look like this

Answer (score 0):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/admin")]
public class AdminController : ApiController
{
    DBEntities _context;
    public AdminController()
    {
        _context = new DBEntities();
    }
    [Route("GetUsers")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
    {

        return new string[] { "Muhammad","Ali"};
    }
}
```

URL: **http://localhost:57368/api/admin/GetUsers**

Comment: its still not working sir. I have created the project in MVC template but have added web api in references by downloading from nuget package manager and have also registered in Global.asax

Comment: How do you know attribute routing is enabled, or that it wants to be used? Why did you just provide a code dump answer with no explanation?

Answer (score 0):

you should use  'RoutePrefix' and   'Route' attributes. API should know how to navigate the incoming request to an action. this attributes help you. don't forget add this namespace ' using System.Web.Http'.

```
using System.Web.Http

[RoutePrefix("api/admin")]
public class AdminController : ApiController
{
    DBEntities _context;
    public AdminController()
    {
         _context = new DBEntities();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUsers")]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetUsers()
    {

        return new string[] { "Muhammad","Ali"};
    }
}
```

Comment: its still not working sir. I have created the project in MVC template but have added web api in references by downloading from nuget package manager and have also registered in Global.asax

Comment: @Muhammad Ali are change the RouteConfig class?

Comment: sir i just figured out and have answered my own question, please review it.

Answer (score 0):

In the Global.asax i registered Api using  **GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register)**
but issue was that i placed it at the bottom due to which MVC took precedence and when i called api/admin it gave error saying no resourse was found beacuse MVC was in action.
I added this GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) at the top and in ApplicationStart() in Gloabl.asax and it worked fine.